# A ball was thrown horizontally but it has zero horizontal initial velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, textbook-erratum

A question I faced reads

> "A ball is thrown horizontally from a height of 25m and hits the ground with a speed that is 4 times its initial speed. What is the initial speed?".

It said the ball was thrown horizontally. But when you look at the solution, it reads "the y component of the initial velocity is 2gd while the x component is 0". Is it possible for a ball thrown horizontally to have 0 horizontal initial velocity and has vertical velocity? It's very confusing to me.

Comment: No, not possible, unless $x, y$ axis are switched deliberately.  Also what's a $d$ in expression $2gd$? For initial velocity to be consistent d must have time units, but it's notation would be strange then. So task is full of confusion.

Comment: "Thrown horizontally" would be understood by most of us to mean that the horizontal component of the velocity at the instant when the ball left the "hand" that threw it was _not_ zero and, that the vertical component _was_ zero. Also, if we were free to choose our own coordinate system in which to describe the motion, many of us would choose one with a horizontal axis labelled, "x", and a vertical axis labelled, "y".

Answer (score 8):

I agree, the solution as stated makes no sense. My guess is that this is the solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question in, erm ..., question has two straightforward solutions. First, find the final velocity in the vertical direction using either kinematics or energy.

Kinematics:

1. Write the kinematics equation for the height as a function of time.
2. Solve this equation for the time. This value represents how long it takes things to fall 25 meters (presumably on Earth).
3. Use the kinematics velocity equation to find the vertical velocity as a function of time, and then find the final vertical velocity.

Energy:

1. Set the initial energy (height and unknown horizontal velocity) equal to the final energy (unknown horizontal velocity and vertical velocity).
2. Solve for the final vertical velocity and simplify.

If you did both, confirm that you have the same answer here. In either case, next write the equation for the final speed (add velocity components in quadrature) given that the final speed equals 4 times the initial horizontal velocity. Substitute the final velocity found earlier into this equation and then solve for the initial horizontal velocity.

Regarding your question about the solutions manual ... it's hard to tell since the passage has no context and you didn't quote the questionable passage verbatim. Unless you did, in which case there are actually 2 glaring errors.

Regarding the idea that the initial horizontal velocity must not be 0, this is plainly false. While I would certainly re-check my math, the final velocity condition could absolutely lead one to find that the initial velocity was exactly 0. In other words, a limiting case of a throw is a drop. This is an abuse of English, but physics can take it.

Comment: My experience is that solutions to problems in work books may simply be wrong. I've even seen mistakes in the online videos offered that give step by step solutions!